# Error: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed when there is no NA value fitted in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I have been checking here to find a similar problem and I couldn't see, even though I saw the same error message.

So let say I have a data:

```
temp = data.frame(ID = c(1:5),
Pl = c("11","12",NA,"14",NA), Pl2 = c("11","11","12","14","14"))
```

> ```
> ID   Pl Pl2
>  1   11  11
>  2   12  11
>  3 <NA>  12
>  4   14  14
>  5 <NA>  14`
> ```

And I wanted to create the fourth column with the conditions:

- If `Pl1` == `Pl2` then desired output is `0` for the forth column
- If `Pl1` == `NA` then desired output is `NA` for the forth column
- for the conditions which should be logically where `Pl1` != `Pl2`,
  then      desired output is `1` for the forth column.

In the end, I came up with this code which I got the error message:

```
for (i in nrow(temp)){
  if (temp[i,2] == temp[i,3]) { 
    temp[i,4] = "0"
  } else if (is.na(temp[i,2])) {
    temp[i,4] = NA
  } else (temp[i,4] = "1")
}

Error in if (temp[i, 2] == temp[i, 3]) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

So I can't see the any syntax/operator error but there might be some logical thing?

Comment: The last `else` presents no conditions, so the code tu run has to be between `{}`.

Comment: so for the end, this should work then;
`} else {temp[i,4] = "1"}
}`

but this time, there will be no condition..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can just do a comparison and coerce it to binary

```
with(temp, as.integer(Pl != Pl2))
```

Or

```
with(temp, as.integer(!(NA^(is.na(Pl))* (Pl == Pl2))))
```

---

In the OP'code, the it is looping through `nrow` i.e. a single number instead it should be either `1:nrow(temp)` or more correct `seq_len(nrow(temp))`

```
for (i in 1:nrow(temp)){
  if (temp[i,2] == temp[i,3] & !is.na(temp[i,2])) { 
    temp[i,4] <- "0"
  }else if (is.na(temp[i,2])){
   temp[i,4] <- NA
   } else {
     temp[i,4] <- "1"
   }

}

temp[,4]
#[1] "0" "1" NA  "0" NA
```

Comment: @DSA Your example have columns `Pl` and `Pl2` where is `Pl1`?

Comment: @DSA Your logic seems to be `with(temp, as.integer(!(NA^(is.na(Pl))* (Pl == Pl2))))` which gets the same answer

Comment: Sorry, comment edited as below:
I can see it, but I have two situations for where `Pl` != `Pl2` and  which is where `Pl` - `Pl2` have different values and  `Pl` has a NA value. So I wanted to start with `Pl` == `Pl2`. I actually didn't get the logic of your solution, even I could see the code might work in that way.

Comment: that's working well of course, but I really want to know what's wrong with the if statements' behavior in the question. Also, you solution is integer based, If I want to print more than 0s and 1s, I should be able to do it with a loop.

Comment: @DSA Updated the post